# Vectorizing labels detection of a vector (dataset) in Octave for multi class Logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization, octave, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

While implementing Logistic regression with multi-features and with multi classes (my chosen data set has classes 1,2,3,4 and 5) of the *m* (>100) sample data with classes between 1 and 5. I tried to find out the no. of unique labels/classes and also put them as a vector. I could write the below code with Y as a column vector of size (m,1)

```
classes = [Y(1,1)]; #Initializing classes
for i = 2:m
    count = 0;
    for j = 1:length(classes)
        if Y(i,1) == classes(j,1)
            count = count + 1;
        end;
    end
    if count ==0
        classes = [classes; Y(i,1)];
    end
end
```

This gave me the list of unique labels in the vector Y. However, I was wondering if there's any better way of writing this code (the above lines of code appears childish to me), especially by vectorization. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, it would help to see a small sample of `classes` and your desired output

Comment: at first glance, you're constantly expanding `classes`. for large data sets this can result in significant code slowdown. if you can know final size of `classes` beforehand, it would be best to preallocate the size. if you can put an upper bound on it, you can preallocate and then trim it as your last step. (a bit memory inefficient, but likely much faster than repeated expansions)

Comment: @NickJ I'm not getting what you want to say. I've already listed the Classes above. Listing that again (1,2,3,4,5). Since the classes size for this ex. is only 5, classes array is not constantly expanding but only when a new class label is found. So, at the end of this code, only 5 no's are present in that array. I ran this and it is working. Willing to see if this can be vectorized!

Comment: Any time inside a loop you have something like a = [a, i], you are going to be expanding a each iteration.  It works, but it's expensive and can result in significant program slowdown, especially for large a or large m.  Since the point of vectorizing is speed, you should also pay attention to other speed traps.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so to look out for an inexpensive way of achieving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if the purpose of the code is just to generate a list of the unique values in Y, you could just use `unique(Y)`. for example:

```
>> m = 10;
>> Y = floor(rand(m,1)*5+1)
Y =

   5
   1
   5
   4
   2
   2
   1
   5
   1
   4

>> unique(Y)
ans =

   1
   2
   4
   5
```

now, the output of your function has them in order they first appear in the list. e.g.,

```
classes = 

   5
   1
   4
   2
```

if that is important, you'll need something like this:

```
>> [sortedClasses idx] = unique(Y,"first")
sortedClasses =

   1
   2
   4
   5

idx =

   2
   5
   4
   1

>> unsortedClasess = Y(sort(idx))
unsortedClasess =

   5
   1
   4
   2
```

both `unique` and `sort` are fairly well vectorized for speed. And removing the repeated expansion of `classes` will prevent repeated variable copying that would impose significant overhead if you had a very large number of classes.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. I should've been aware of unique and sort. Thanks.